# Can not import Zipline with Anaconda

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, environment, zipline

So I am trying to import zipline with anaconda. Though due to the fact that zipline requires python 3.5 I created an environment with python 3.5 in it. I did `conda install zipline` in the environment's terminal and it says it has successfully installed, then when I open python within the environment, and I import zipline no errors come up. I also have jupyter notebook installed in the env, when I import zipline in ipython, it causes no errors. But then when I open Jupiter notebook through the environment, then open a new kernel and try to import zipline, it says the module does not exist (I have even imported numpy and other things that are also downloaded and they work fine in the same jupyter notebook tab, and I also I am opening JN through the 3.5 env terminal not the base terminal). Please help, thank you.

EDIT: An example of the code could be

```
import numpy as np 
np.sqrt(16)
```

This will return:

```
4.0
```

Then if I import zipline:

```
!conda install -c quantopian zipline
import zipline as zp
import numpy as np
np.sqrt(16)
```

There is no output, it just skips to the next cell without an error popping up, and also the `I[1]` part of the cell changes to `I[*]` instead of `I[2]`
(I am new at python so probably I am doing something wrong)

what I get from pip show zipline in the terminal

```
Name: zipline
Version: 1.3.0
Summary: A backtester for financial algorithms.
Home-page: http://zipline.io
Author: Quantopian Inc.
Author-email: opensource@quantopian.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\benito\anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages
Requires: pip, setuptools, Logbook, pytz, numpy, requests-file, scipy, pandas, pandas-datareader, patsy, statsmodels, python-dateutil, six, requests, Cython, cyordereddict, bottleneck, contextlib2, decorator, networkx, numexpr, bcolz, click, toolz, multipledispatch, MarkupSafe, Mako, sqlalchemy, alembic, sortedcontainers, intervaltree, lru-dict, empyrical, tables, trading-calendars
```

Comment: Try copy-pasting this exactly the same way: `conda install -c Quantopian zipline`

Comment: I am still having the same problem. If I import zipline without what you said, then I get the module not found error, but If I do add it then I get the same problem as above: there is no output.

Comment: What do you get when you type `pip show zipline`? Type in terminal

Comment: I have added the output of pip show zipline to my answer at the end, it would not fit in this comment.

Comment: _But then when I open Jupiter notebook through the environment, then open a new kernel and try to import zipline, it says the module does not exist_ I'm not super familiar with Jupyter Notebooks, but isn't that to be expected? I thought you were supposed to create an environment for each kernel.

Comment: How do create an environment with each kernel (I am not well acquainted with Jupiter notebook either)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is it is required to install jupyter notebook for every environment. So at first make sure that you have installed jupyter notebook correctly on the required environment. If you have installed it correctly then open jupyter notebook and in a code cell write any one of the following commands and execute the cell.

```
!conda install -c quantopian zipline -y
```

or

```
!conda install -c quantopian/label/ci zipline -y
```

After this execution import the library again.

Comment: Okay so I did this and it worked and you are amazing thank you!! I have pulling my hair out because of this for days (I cannot upvote your question because of my reputation, I only have 11), though now when I run the code in the cell with that, the code will not run. So it just skips to the next cell without printing the output

Comment: You can have a look on this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zipline/4xv8JY2PsIo

Comment: So it seems like he is having the same problems I am, but I dont see an answer to our problems. I dont know what else to do. I have created a new env 3 times, everything checks out, but then I open jupyter notebook through the environment and it says it does not exist. And what you said helped because now their is no module error, but now I get no output when I run the code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot or specific error name ?

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f64b1fa2c717> in <module>
----> 1 import zipline as zp

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zipline'`

Comment: Actually I don't have any idea about your code so I don't know anything about your no output scenario.

Comment: So I have added to the question up top(there is an example of code with my problem), if you can take a look to see. I changed the question as an edit because I could not fit the answer to your question down here in the comments (thank you again for your help :) )

Comment: I have added some changes to my answer. Try the new one and write print(np.sqrt(16)) instead of np.sqrt(16).

Comment: I have tried that then it says the package is successfully installed, but then it says that zipline does not exist.